# GCE managed group (autoscaling) - Proxy/Load Balancer for both HTTP(S) and TCP requests

Tags: google-compute-engine, load-balancing, static-ip-address

I have an autoscaling istance group, i need to setup a Proxy/Load balancer that take request and send it to the istance group.

I thinked to use a Load balancer, but I need to grab both HTTP(S) and TCP requests.
There is some way (or some workaround) to solve this?

EDIT: The problem is that from TCP LB settings i can set the backend service (the managed group that i need to set) only for one port.

Answer (score 0):

For your use case, a single load balancing configuration available on Google Cloud Platform will not be able to serve the purpose. On the other hand, since you are using managed instance groups (Autoscaling), it can not be used as backend for 2 different load balancers.

As per my understanding, the closest you can go is by using [Network load balancing (TCP)](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/network) and install [SSL certificate](http://www.howto-expert.com/how-to-get-https-setting-up-ssl-on-your-website/) to handle HTTPS requests
on the instance level.

Comment: What do you mean for "setting up SSL on the instance level"?

Comment: I have updated my post on the SSL part.  I hope this clarifies.

Comment: But load balancer doesn't block the request to HTTPS? 
And in that case, i have the same problem. I can't point my HTTPS requests to a static ip, if that istance "die", ip change :/

Comment: Network load balancer (NLB) will not block the HTTPS requests. [NLB](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/network/index) is a pass-through/non-proxied load balancer which will put your resources behind a single anycast IP address (static external) and preserves client IP addresses.

NLB [picks an instance](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/network/#load_distribution_algorithm) based on a hash of the source IP and port, destination IP and port, and protocol . (cont.)

Comment: (cont). This means that incoming TCP connections are spread across instances and each new connection may go to a different instance. All packets for a connection are directed to the same instance until the connection is closed.

If an instance in the group stops, crashes, or is deleted by an action other than the instance groups commands, the [managed instance group](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/#managed_instance_groups) automatically recreates the instance so it can resume its processing tasks.